# How to set sscanf() to ignore characters at start of string?

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I have a string as below

```
 char row[]="11/12/1999 foo:bar some data..... ms:12123343 hot:32";
```

I want insert 'ms' val to int variable by using sscanf.
But I don't know how to configure ssscanf to ignore first data in row.
I try blow but don't do the job.

```
int i;
sscanf(row,".*ms:%d",i);
```

Comment: `sscanf(strstr(row, "ms:") + 3, "%d", &i);`

Comment: If you know there's only one colon, you could also `sscanf(row, "%*[^:]:%d", &i);`.

Comment: no there's some other colon

Comment: @herzlshemuelian try my answer, I also given a link there open second answer

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan thanks I wrote to a comment about your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, rather than using sscanf() to ignore data, your best bet is to use another function to get the part of the string you want.

I suggest [strstr()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html).
For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char row[] = "11/12/1999 foo:54654 some data..... ms:12123343 hot:32";
    char *ms;
    int i;

    ms = strstr(row, "ms:");
    if (ms == NULL) /* error: no "ms:" in row */;
    if (sscanf(ms + 3, "%d", &i) != 1) /* error: invalid data */;
    printf("ms value is %d.\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

You can see the [code running at ideone](http://ideone.com/4We3UN).

Comment: My answer is for C. In C++ you would use `string` rather than arrays of characters and possibly a different approach to the problem: I don't know C++.

Comment: You can [see a new version of the code above that accepts input from *stdin*](http://ideone.com/RUtAPU).

Answer (score 0):

The joker is used in shells, but `sscanf` does not treat the `*` character this way.

> **7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function**
>   — An optional assignment-suppressing character *.

There are several solutions. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *pend = strrchr(row, ':');
sscanf(pend, ":%d", &i);
```

You can also use scanset from `scanf` or `strstr`.